# Java : String.matches()

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to determine whether a string consists of only two words, with one space character between them. The first word should only include alphanumeric characters. The second should include only numbers. An example is: `asd 15`

I would like to use `String.matches`. How can I do this or which regex should I use?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You look for something like:

```
String regex = "^[A-Za-z]+ [0-9]+$";
```

Explanation:

```
^         the beginning of the string (nothing before the next token)
[A-Za-z]+ at least one, but maybe more alphabetic chars (case insensitive)
          a single space (hard to see :) )
[0-9]+    at least one, but maybe more digits
$         end of the string (nothing after the digits)
```

Comment: Thanks to Binyamin Sharet and Juan Alberto Lopez Caval. Both solutions worked, additionally, i want to check whether first word can only include numbers at the head of it, how can i do this ?

Comment: The first word doesn't look alphanumeric to me. The numerics are missing.

Comment: @userunknown - I misread the question, but seems like that what the OP meant for (see his example)

Comment: If the question is wrong, it should be changed. An accepted answer which doesn't answer the question is pretty irritating.

Answer (score 4):

You can give this regex a try

```
"[A-Za-z0-9]+\\s[0-9]+"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out: `String pattern = new String("^[0-9]*[A-Za-z]+ [0-9]+$")`

Comment: The question asked for alphanumeric strings, which would be `^[0-9A-Za-z]+...`.

Comment: Please read the second part of the comment from Predoryx... Thanks to Binyamin Sharet and Juan Alberto Lopez Caval. Both solutions worked, additionally, <b>i want to check whether first word can only include numbers at the head of it</b>, how can i do this ?

Comment: Is your answer an answer to the question or an answer to the comment?